# How to add icon to a custom grub boots script?

Tags: grub2, dual-boot, icons

I downloaded [primeos](https://primeos.in/) and copied `system.sfs`, `ramdisk.img` `kernel`, `install.img`, `initrd.img` from the ISO to `~/primeos` and created an empty directory called `~/primeos/data`.

To boot, I created a custom menu entry `PrimeOS` with the following boot sequence* using [grub-customizer](https://launchpad.net/%7Edanielrichter2007/+archive/ubuntu/grub-customizer):

```
insmod part_gpt
search --file --no-floppy --set=root /home/joe/primeos/system.sfs
linux /home/joe/primeos/kernel root=/dev/ram0 androidboot.selinux=permissive buildvariant=userdebug SRC=/home/joe/primeos
initrd /home/joe/primeos/initrd.img
```

- I'm using [Tela GRUB theme](https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1307852/).
- `elementary 5.1`, `Windows 10` & `Parrot 4.7` are on different partitions, while `PrimeOS` is on `elementary`'s disk.
- Since Tela theme does not have an icon for `Parrot 4.7` entry I added an icon at `/boot/grub/themes/Tela/icons/parrot.png` of 32 x 32 size and it works just fine.

[image: Grub Customizer]

- PrimeOS works just fine.

My question is how do I add an icon for `PrimeOS` custom boot entry?

> I've tried adding a 32 x 32 `prime.png` and `primeos.png` at `/boot/grub/themes/Tela/icons/` separately, but both of them does not seem the work. The grub menu entry is working but is without icon.

**Edit**: Here's how my current boot menu looks like
[image]

---

**System Info**:

```bsh
joe in ~ at eOS via  base 
⮚.⮚.⮚ neofetch
         eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee            joe@eOS 
      eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee         ------- 
    eeeee  eeeeeeeeeeee   eeeee       OS: elementary OS 5.1.5 Hera x86_64 
  eeee   eeeee       eee     eeee     Host: Dell System XPS L502X 
 eeee   eeee          eee     eeee    Kernel: 5.3.0-59-generic 
eee    eee            eee       eee   Uptime: 3 hours, 28 mins 
eee   eee            eee        eee   Packages: 2364 
ee    eee           eeee       eeee   Shell: zsh 5.4.2 
ee    eee         eeeee      eeeeee   Resolution: 1366x768 
ee    eee       eeeee      eeeee ee   DE: Pantheon 
eee   eeee   eeeeee      eeeee  eee   WM: Mutter(Gala) 
eee    eeeeeeeeee     eeeeee    eee   Terminal: io.elementary.t 
 eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee    eeeee    CPU: Intel i5-2410M (4) @ 2.900GHz 
  eeeeeeee eeeeeeeeeeee      eeee     GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GT 525M 
    eeeee                 eeeee       GPU: Intel 2nd Generation Core Processor Family 
      eeeeeee         eeeeeee         Memory: 3503MiB / 11875MiB 
         eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee
```

> - BIOS & MBR system.
> - *Reference: https://www.fosslicious.com/2018/12/how-to-install-primeos-in-ubuntu.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sorry nobody answered in a long time but I came across your question when finding out the answer myself.

You should read this post:
https://superuser.com/questions/1559269/customize-icons-in-a-grub-theme

I am assuming that your primeos entry is a custom menu entry in this file:

```
/etc/grub.d/40_custom
```

If that is the case, you are going to want to add a --class attribute to the menuentry like so

```
menuentry 'PrimeOS' --class primeos {
...
}
```

where primeos matches the filename in your iconset:

```
/boot/grub/themes/Tela/icons/primeos.png
```

after editing your /etc/grub.d/40_custom run this command to update grub for your changes to take effect

```
sudo update-grub
```

I had to do a similar thing to add custom tela icons to custom Windows and MacOSX entries in my grub config, this mapped the menu entries to the icons in the theme:

```
menuentry 'Windows 10' --class windows {
    search --fs-uuid --no-floppy --set=root BCD4-0123
    chainloader (${root})/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
}

menuentry 'Mac OSX Big Sur' --class macosx {
    search --fs-uuid --no-floppy --set=root 26BA-E00C
    chainloader (${root})/EFI/BOOT/BOOTx64.efi
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hey, my system setup has changed, but not my interests :) So I'll check it out when I'm ready. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: Hi, I've circled back to this and found this working. Thanks a lot!